# Why am I getting only one result with "craft()->db->createCommand()"?

Tags: plugin-development, plugins, database

Why am I getting only one result with the following query?

```
$query = craft()->db->createCommand();
$entryRecord = $query->select('craft_content.field_releaseDate, craft_content.title, craft_entries.id, craft_entries.dateCreated')->from('content')->join('entries', 'craft_content.elementId = craft_entries.id')->where('craft_entries.sectionId=2')->queryRow();
```

Also the documentation says that the table prefix isn't required, but this doesn't work most of the time, weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Completely untested but it looks like you're just querying a row instead of all.

Update `queryRow()` to `queryAll()`

Answer (score 4):

The table prefix *isn't* required, and will mess up your results if you add it.

However, when you refer to a new table (as in "join"), you'll want to alias the table for consistent use:

```
join('entries entries', 'content.elementId = entries.id')
```

The first `entries` is your table reference (sans prefix).

The second `entries` is your new alias, referenced by `entries.id`.

Regardless, [Peter's answer](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/4723/45) is spot on.